# Default Fonts available in Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, macos, safari

I have created a HTML page which uses Calibri font. Now this font is applied and seen on all Desktop Window browsers (IE/FF,etc), but I cannnot see the same on MAC Safari (& iPhone Safari).

So I wanted to know which are the default fonts available for Safari (MAC/iPhone) ?

Also any alternate font which comes closest to Calibri and available across browsers ?

Please suggest.

PS: I was thinking of Cufon JS, but that is secondary and it might make my file heavier.

Comment: Safari does not come with any fonts. You see Calibri on your PC because Calibri comes with Office 2007 (and later) and Windows Vista (and later).

Comment: So what is the alternate for Safari (closest to Calibri) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common fonts to all versions of Windows & Mac equivalents

http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Comment: Try the Arial bold style.Feels that its more close to Calibri

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are related to your OS.

Check out fonts available on Mac by going to directory /Library/Fonts
You can check fonts installed for user /Users/username/Library/Fonts on Mac

Comment: Ok...What alternate can I use for Safari i.e. closest to Calibri